# Get instance / reference from jQuery prototype function ($.fn)

Tags: jquery, reference, prototype, instance, custom-data-attribute

I wrote a jQuery plugin that uses a prototype.

Example:

```
  function MyWidgetConstructor(element) {

    this.id = 'test';
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.$element.data('instance', this);

  }

  MyWidgetConstructor.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert('Hello, my ID is: ' + this.id);
  }

  $.fn.myWidget= function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      new MyWidgetConstructor(this);
    });
  };
```

I use the data attribute to save a reference to the widget. This way I can call the prototype methods with instance variables as follows:

```
    jQuery('#myInstance').myWidget();
    jQuery('#myInstance').data('instance').test();
```

However, that is not always working. Is there another way to get to the reference (maybe without the use of a data attribute)?

Comment: can you tell when is is not working?

Comment: It looks just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t2p8U/1/

Comment: I uploaded the widget on another server and there it is not working. :( But the jQuery version is the same: 1.10.2.

Comment: then the reason could be something else....  what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found another approach! One can use a global instance array to manage the different instances.

**Example:**

```
(function ($) {

    window.InstanceCollection = window.InstanceCollection || {};

    $.fn.myWidget = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            new MyWidgetConstructor(this);
        });
    };       

    function MyWidgetConstructor(element) {
        this.id = 'test';
        window.InstanceCollection[this.id] = this;
    }

    MyWidgetConstructor.prototype.sayHello = function () {
        alert('Hello, my ID is: ' + this.id);
    }

})(jQuery)

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#myInstance').myWidget();
    window.InstanceCollection['test'].sayHello();
})
```